# Get cost of each resource everyday in my azure subscription

Tags: python, azure, azure-api-management, azure-cost-calculation

I am trying to get the cost of each and every resource in my azure subscription everyday.
I was thinking to use this link [Azure REST API - Where do I find resource costs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559925/azure-rest-api-where-do-i-find-resource-costs) but i don't have the resource group names for the subscriptions with me.

Answer (score 1):

At the subscription level, Azure provides and ability to track your spending over your whole infrastructure with "Cost Management + Biling". You can preview your cost analysis and see your burning partner overtime. There's also a new functionality in preview so you can see cost by resource for example.

[image]

The above picture is how the cost analysis look like and how you can imagine it.

If you would like to know more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/cost-management-billing-overview

**EDIT**

The above is accessible in Azure portal directly. But I've personally never did it via REST API, but so far I was able to find this and I believe it might help you.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details

Comment: Do you have any example for the same using python or any other lang?

Comment: what is your actual goal to get it with REST API ?

Comment: @catJam Thats correct !!! I want the cost of each resource in the given subscription via rest api everyday.

Comment: @user1312155  I just updated my answer with RESP API solution.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a [blog post](https://www.jeeja.biz/2022/11/11/azure-finops-connect-power-bi-to-azure-cost-management/) about this:

1. You can use the [Azure Cost Management connector in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management)
2. You can [exported daily data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/tutorial-export-acm-data?tabs=azure-portal) in CSV format